# daml repl like GHCI equivalent

Tags: daml

haskell ghci repl is a fantastic way to quickly lookup types and kinds via :t and :k and provides fast feedback loop for hole driven development.

Does DAML have this available via CLI (not VS code tooltip popup). If not, is it on the roadmap to release? or any technical reasons why it cant be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment there is no GHCi equivalent for DAML at the moment and we also don’t have any concrete plans of adding it right now since our efforts are focused on DAML studio. But if we see that there is demand for it, it is definitely something that we could consider so thank you for raising this!

From the technical side `:t` and `:k` commands on expressions over definitions that are defined in files should be relatively straightforward, supporting the addition of new definitions is a bit more complex but should also be doable. Actually running code is probably the most complex but with a bit of effort I expect that you could make it work.

I’d also be interested in why you prefer the GHCi experience over DAML studio. Maybe there is something we could add in DAML studio to help you?

Comment: I find a GHCi like environment provides pleasant UX to explore function behaviour and type info through alt + tab as opposed to navigating to web docs which I have found to suffer high scroll lag and a search bar that doesn't hide after typing in a query. Hole Driven Dev is nicer if you can read the type errors in a separate terminal to alt tab to which ghci provides functionality for (DAML studio presents as a tooltip which needs to be resized and is temporary only). Ill consider writing my own tool for this as a prototype.

Answer (score 0):

I think DAMLi would be a great addition. I believe it would be helpful both when learning and developing with DAML, in particular with bits that have a flavour of more traditional programming.

I would use it.